# Aplicar estilo CSS a elemento ascendente

Tags: css, html5

Necesito **aplicar un estilo concreto a un elemento solo si contiene otro dentro**, de un tipo determinado. Concretando: tengo una lista, algunos de sus elementos tiene un enlace dentro. Quiero ampliar el área *accionable* del enlace a todo su contenedor. Todos los elementos de la lista presentan el mismo *padding*, con independencia de si tiene un enlace en su interior o no, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        /* Reset */
        * {
            -webkit-margin-before: 0;
            -webkit-margin-after:  0;
            -webkit-margin-start:  0;
            -webkit-margin-end:    0;
            -webkit-padding-start: 0;
            background    : transparent;
            border        : 0;
            box-sizing    : border-box;
            font-size     : 100%;
            margin        : 0;
            outline       : 0;
            padding       : 0;
            text-align    : center;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        body {
            padding: 10%;
        }


        /* estilos lista */
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        li {
            background-color: lightpink;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
        }
        li a {
            background-color: salmon;
            padding         : 1rem;
        }
        li,
        li a {
            border-radius : 5px;
            display       : block;
        }
        .padding {
            padding: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="">
            <a href="">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="padding">
            HTML5
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora mismo estoy aplicando un `padding: 1rem`. Consigo el efecto deseado aplicando este *padding* a todos los elementos `a` y a todos los `li` sin un `a` en su interior añadiéndoles la clase:

```
.padding {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Quiero poder prescindir de esta clase "padding" en los `li`. ¿Hay algún selector para lograrlo?

> Editado:

*En [esta página de 2010 (en inglés)](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), se habla de que no existe el "selector ascendente" y posibles sintaxis para crearlo.*

Comment: Creo que en este momento no hay un selector en CSS que lo permita. ¿Qué tal si en lugar de aplicar estilos sobre elementos `li` o `a` los aplica a algún otro elemento que pueda poner como hijo de estos `li` o `a`? Así no tendría que pensar si un `li` contiene un `a`, sino simplemente poner este nuevo elemento (¿`span` tal vez?) en los `li` o `a` que correspondan.

Comment: @Hernán_Alarcón añadir otro elemento sería igual o incluso más complicado que usar la clase sobre los `li` sin `a` que uso ahora mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- padding para todos
- margen negativo para los `a` ( y extra padding )

```css
/* Reset */

* {
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  padding: 10%;
}


/* estilos lista */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: lightpink;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li a {
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: -1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}

li,
li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      HTML5
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      HTML5
    </li>
    <li>
      HTML5
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¡Genial! Muchas gracias. Lo del margen negativo para compensar el *padding* sobrante, me vino a la cabeza en algún momento durante la noche... ahí se quedo.